# replace background images with background color in all screen

Tags: background-color, uicolor

I've facing one problem while developing my application.In my application there are more then 10 screens and have done with design too.But now i want to change whole color of the screen while user can open color picker and selected color will apply on all the screes.

Can any one suggest me that how can i do this one.because i have used lot's of imageview and images too.

Below is the example code where i have used the images in uitableview cell :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CategoriesListCell";

    CategoriesListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[CategoriesListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        int row = indexPath.row * 2;

        NSLog(@"row:::%d",row);


        UIButton *btnCategoriesLeft = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, btnWidth, rowHeight)];
        UIImage *imgButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgbutton"];
        [btnCategoriesLeft setImage:imgButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnCategoriesLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCatTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btnCategoriesLeft setTag:row];

        //Set Transpernt images
        UIImageView *imgViewLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 88, 53)];
        [imgViewLeft setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",row]]];
        [imgViewLeft setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [btnCategoriesLeft addSubview:imgViewLeft];


        //Set Title of label
        UILabel *lblCategoriesTitleLeft = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 140, 20)];
        lblCategoriesTitleLeft.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblCategoriesTitleLeft.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [lblCategoriesTitleLeft setFont:FONT_WITH_SIZE_REGULAR(15.0)];
        [lblCategoriesTitleLeft setText:[arrListOfCategories objectAtIndex:row]];
        [lblCategoriesTitleLeft setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [btnCategoriesLeft addSubview:lblCategoriesTitleLeft];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:btnCategoriesLeft];


        UIButton *btnCategoriesRight = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btnWidth, 0, btnWidth, rowHeight)];
        imgButton = [imgButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:imgButton.size.width/2 topCapHeight:imgButton.size.height/2];
        [btnCategoriesRight setImage:imgButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnCategoriesRight setTag:row +1];
        [btnCategoriesRight addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCatTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        //Set Transpernt images
        UIImageView *imgViewRight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 88, 53)];
        [imgViewRight setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",row+1]]];
        [imgViewRight setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [btnCategoriesRight addSubview:imgViewRight];


        //Set Title of label
        UILabel *lblCategoriesTitleRight = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 80, 140, 20)];
        lblCategoriesTitleRight.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblCategoriesTitleRight.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [lblCategoriesTitleRight setFont:FONT_WITH_SIZE_REGULAR(15.0)];
        [lblCategoriesTitleRight setText:[arrListOfCategories objectAtIndex:row+1]];
        [lblCategoriesTitleRight setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [btnCategoriesRight addSubview:lblCategoriesTitleRight];

        [[cell contentView] addSubview:btnCategoriesRight];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about how your sample code correlates to the question you're asking. If I understand this correctly, you would like to change the background color of all 10 or more screens with a slider. Try setting up red, blue, and green sliders and assigning global variables via the app delegate.

Add three sliders to interface builder.
Then set up three UISlider outlets.

**YourSliderViewController.h**

```
@interface YourViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISlider *redSlider;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISlider *blueSlider;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISlider *greenSlider;
@end
```

**YourSliderViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender{
float red = self.redSlider.value;
float green = self.greenSlider.value;
float blue = self.blueSlider.value;
UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red
                                    green:green
                                     blue:blue
                                    alpha:1.0];
self.view.backgroundColor = newColor;
}
```

*The following is to make your RGB sliders accessible to all classes. That way you can set self.view.background = newColor in any other ViewController inside -viewDidLoad.*
Create a pointer to the AppDelegate. I called mine appDel.

**MyXcodeProject-Prefix.pch**

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
AppDelegate *appDel;
#endif
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *newColor;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```